# Is there a way to exclude video results from Google Search?

Tags: google-search, video

Sometimes I am specifically looking for a written tutorial on a subject (in a blog format, etc), but all I can find are video tutorials in Google Search results. This is especially frustrating when I'm at work, where it looks bad to be watching YouTube videos on the job, but I still sometimes need a tutorial on something.

Is there a way to *exclude* video results from search? (Ideally this would also exclude pages that simply embed a video tutorial and reference it.) Thanks.

Comment: I have been searching for this answer for months and as far as I can find, it appears to be "there are some search term hacks to do a weak and unreliable job of approximating it, but the truth is it's not really possible". I'm looking for another search engine, Google is getting less and less useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would like to exclude any sort of video from a Google search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112569/would-like-to-exclude-any-sort-of-video-from-a-google-search)

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Yes, it does. Thanks for linking. And for cases where something cannot easily be found outside of YouTube, I have discovered [YouTubeTranscript.com](https://youtubetranscript.com), which extracts the transcript from a video and displays that text all at once. :-)